# If function for cell contents

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check that if the content for a certain range is true, it will perform a function.

```
    With Sheets(1).[A1:A95]
        If .Cells.Value = "text" Then
            'Perform function
        End If
    End With
```

But I'm getting a Type Mismatch error. Help please.

Comment: Are you checking if any cell in that range has the search term `"text"`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I have 7 texts that needs to be checked in that certain range and each text has a specific function to call.

Comment: See the answer that i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check each cell in the range for whatever you are testing for then, try it this way.

```
Dim cCell As Range

For Each cCell in Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$A$95")
    'To test to ensure cCell.Value is what you expect(can remove once working)
    Debug.Print cCell.Value
    If cCell.Value ="whateveryouwanttotestfor" Then
        'Call your function here
        Call myFunction
    End If

Next cCell
```

To test for multiple values of cCell use Select Case

```
For Each cCell in Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$A$95")
    Select Case cCell.Value
        Case "text1"
           Call text1Function
        Case "text2"
           Call text2Function
        'Do the rest that you need
    End Select
Next cCell
```

Comment: Also possible via `For Each cCell in Sheets(1).[A1:A95]`. Just in case the OP like it that way :P

Comment: Correct, just prefer showing the standard way when not sure how advanced the poster is.

Comment: @dinotom  This work thanks but I'm having another issue. The if function doesn't seem to work. The regardless if the text is false, it still performs the function and I have up to 7 text that needs to be checked with 7 different functions for it.

Comment: @Marco... Add Debug.Print cCell.Value before the If statement and step thru the code to ensure that the value coming from the cell is what you expect, otherwise the If statement should work as shown.

Comment: @Dinotom - Man you've been a very great help today. The 'Debug.Print cCell.Value' works, however it's not checking the other 'IF' statements on my code. I have 7 'IF' statements for each specific text that needs to be checked.

Comment: That Debug line will only show the cell value in that specific For loop. The if statement should jump to whatever "If" value that debug line is showing you.